# Fill in command input

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I'm trying to enter input without typing anything I'm trying to put the input in the command.

I've seen people try this:

```
printf 'argument\n' | command
```

Or

```
command <<< "argument\n"
```

I don't know if what I'm doing is command specific but neither of these work for what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to zip a file with a password:

```
zip -r -e test.zip test_zip/
```

`-e` is for password input (this isn't the part I was talking). I set the password to `test1234`.

When I unzip the file I try things like this:

```
printf 'test1234\n' | unzip test.zip
```

But it still asks for password input.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you bother reading `man unzip`?  Specifically the option `-P`?

Comment: Thank you @tink! I probably should've done that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-P` argument

```
unzip -P <password> <zipfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Linux command line, try using `echo`.

```
echo 'test1234' | unzip test.zip
```

Comment: When I said I tried things like ``printf 'test1234' | unzip test.zip`` I thought people would've assumed I used echo too. Sorry it doesn't work for me.